# Load Panel from Another Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I created 2 Forms, Form1 with a Panel, and Form2 with a Panel. On Form2 I want to design the controls, which then I load within Form1 dynamicly. The idea is that I can design with VS any amount of forms, but then use those panels inside the forms to load into Form1 dynamically.

Trouble is, form2 uses a Dataset + Databind, which then stops working when loaded into the Form1.

Method I tried within Form1:

```
        From2 from2 = new Form2();

        for (int i = 0; i < cf.Form2.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Add(cf.Form2.Controls[i]);
        }
```

Comment: I assume this is winforms and have tagged it accordingly.  If not, please fix the tags to include the actual paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

*This is assuming I accurately read your meaning*

As you're discovering, that appropach isn't feasible.

A far better approach would be to create a [User Control](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/10/13/winforms-user-controls-101.aspx) containing the panel.  In your User Control, you can expose a public method called DataBind() that takes the data source as an input parameter, and within that method, bind the data.

It's easier to load a USer Control dynamically than to load a form dynamically.

In the User Control, you'll simply add a method as such.  (Modify this as necessary to suit your needs)

```
public void BindData(System.Data.DataTable t)
{
   GridView1.DataSource = t;
   if(t.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      FirstNameTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(t.Rows[0]["FirstName"])
   }
}
```

In your form, you call it as such (Of course, there should be error handling, etc - this is a bare-bones example of how to do what I'm describing.)

```
System.Data.DataTable t = new System.Data.DataTable;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ad = new System.Data.DataAdapter(sql, connectionstring);
ad.Fill(t);

MyUserControl myControl= new MyUserControl();
myControl.BindData(t);
```

Comment: I have never conciderd User Controls, thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: Ok, I loaded the User Control, but not sure how to add the DataBind()

Comment: It doesn't have to be call DataBind().  It can be anything you want.  You simply need to add a function to the UserControl and mark it as public.  Then, from the actual form that the user control is placed on, you can call it.  I'll modify my answer with some pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding 100% what your saying, so correct me if I'm wrong. You want to load child items from various forms and display them dynamically on form1? I'm not sure why you want to do this.

Why not rather use User Controls, you can make different user controls as needed and load these controls into your form1 as needed.

If your not sure how to do this, right click on your project>add new item>user control and play around.

Comment: The idea is that someone else designs the form2 with a panel control, and that person can change it as they desire without me having to update the code everytime there is a design change for one. Another reason, I could have use TabPanel, but the program layout will look over clumped with too many tabs, so the idea came to dynamically add controls to one panel in the main form1. However, designing the other forms became easier in their own forms.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have stated, the solution that you need to use is to create UserControls for these types of situations.  The reason that what you're trying to do won't work is that controls are specifically designed to only ever work on a single Form.  If you try to add a control to multiple forms it will only be able to be successfully added to one.  This is even true for UserControls.  You *won't* be able to just make one usercontrol and then add it to two forms.  The advantage of a user control is that you can place all of the code for creating, initializing, and using some section of functionality into a separate location from the form.  You will want to create two separate instances of the same user control that you add two two separate forms.  The advantage is simply that the code for creating the panel, and everything that goes within it or deals with it, is re-used.